# How wrong is it to use code to avoid a license limitation?

Tags: licenses

A situation that has been brought to me recently, and I really don't know the proper answer.

Suppose a company is using a license that is cheaper than the Enterprise license, and that does not have all CRUD access to the Product standard object. The license allows only "read".

It is possible to create a page/component in which the user is able to do all CRUD operations to a Product record. But since this is being used to avoid a license limitation, is this wrong?

Comment: I can drive my car at way above the speed limit of a road. But I wouldn't be surprised to lose my driving license if I did that.

Comment: That's a nice analogy, Keith. But do you know where can I find a reference for a document that specifies things like this? I'm not sure if the Terms of Service describe something like this.

Comment: geez - I don't even know where to begin here but would start by considering one's moral compass

Comment: Just to be clear here, cropredy, this is a customer requirement, not mine. And trust me, I've warned them about the possible outcome of doing this several times. I asked this question here in hopes that someone could link me to a document with this written on it, so just maybe I could make them change their minds.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira I've added a reference to the MSA with a specific article. If that's not enough for your client, I would really suggest you get out of there and tell them you do not want to have anything to do with what they want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Master Subscription Agreement](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/legal/salesforce_MSA.pdf) that you sign when you buy licenses from Salesforce.

Article 4.4(g) states that you will not

> permit direct or indirect access
>   to or use of any Service or Content in a way that circumvents a contractual usage limit

I'm sure there are other parts in there that prevent the use case you're describing, but I think this in itself should say enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for finding this! It is exactly what I need. :)

Answer (score 6):

Your use of salesforce.com is bound by contractual agreements. By intentionally bypassing license restrictions, you are in breach of contract. You may be subject to retroactive license fees, suspension or termination of services, as well as other legal remedies that may arise from breach of contract. While I have not heard of any organization actually getting as far as that, the rules are in place to allow this to happen, and you don't want to be that organization. I can't find the exact document that outlines this, but my best advice for you is to not risk it. You might get away with it for a while, but if you get caught, it could cost you a lot more than if you'd just bought the appropriate licenses to begin with.